# Yii prioritize job

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii

Hye everyone, Im creating a library system using Yii Bootstrap framework. The Library have the functionality for booking etc. The problem that im having now is when my book have 1 stock in database. Basically what i did was if two users trying to reserve my book then the system will check for the time that the user made the booking. Then it will allowed one user to reserve the book.

Then i try to do a testing where 2 users trying to reserve the book at the same time and it captured both users :(

Explanantion in detail:

Book in stock = 1

2 users trying to reserve this book at the same tim

How to do prioritize on which user should have the book and which one shouldnt have the book.
Now in my database i have two users with the same time (include with seconds)

Comment: Maybe consider `milliseconds` aswell? Otherwise it shouldn't happen so often that two users will offer the same last book in stock in your shop at the very same milliseconds. Or use a booking queue.

Comment: Thanks bro i've tried to put unique to solve this problem however it seem i cant specified my own error message it always show "CDB failed to execute the SQL Duplicate Entry". U said to used millisecond. Now im using this for my format  'Y-m-d H:i:s'   what char should i use after s

Comment: You shouldn't set your timestamp column to `UNIQUE` because whats with the other users then ordering at the same time but different books? How do you store the date and time in the database? Whats the field definition? `DATETIME`? `TIMESTAMP`? I would store it as raw `Unix Timestamp` using a `TIMESTAMP` field and then do something like `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp_column) FROM booking_table` or `INSERT INTO booking_table (timestamp_column) VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp))`.